# Making text stay within a div

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems having one div of text stay within it's container. Everything else scales okay but the text trails outside of it and I'm not sure how to fix it.

CSS:

```
.design-bg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("/images/apicture.jpg")
}

.design-winner {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.design-winner-desc {
    width: 950px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}

.design-winner-pics {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="design-bg">

<div class="design-winner">
    <img src="/images/picture.jpg" style="border-radius: 50%;">
</div>
<div class="design-winner-desc">
    <p><span style="font-size: 24px; color: #225083"><strong>Name here</strong></span><br><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #225083">Maybe a role here<br><br>Blah blah blah text text text</span></p>
</div>

<div class="design-winner-pics">
    <img src="/images/picture2.jpg">
    <img src="/images/picutre3.jpg">
    <img src="/images/picture4.jpg">
    <img src="/images/picture5.jpg">
</div>
```

This is what it looks like on a browser:

[image: browser]

And this is what happens when i shrink it down:

[image: smaller version]

Comment: You have a fixed width on your .design-winner-desc rule change it to max-width

Comment: You want it to be responsive to account for differences in screen size. You media queries.

Comment: @JulianEspinosa that solved it! Woohoo! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `design-bg` width set as %, and the other divs - in pixels. Try to change there to % ?

Like this (and you can set minimum-width in pixels):

```
.design-bg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1080px;
    background-image: url("/images/apicture.jpg")
}

.design-winner {
    height: 130px;
    width: 9%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.design-winner-desc {
    width: 89%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm have you tried the 
clear: both;

command in

```
.design-winner-desc {
clear: both;
width: 950px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
margin-left: 130px;
```

}

^like this

i'm not entirely sure if thats the problem but it removes any floating elements and its worth a try i guess :D

I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Try making the width of .design-winner-desc to max width minus the width of .design-winner. You can do it with the calc() function if you are developing to CSS3-compliant browsers.

```
.design-winner-desc {
    width: calc(100% - 130px);
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
```